# How to load external Vue components when I not use npm

Tags: vue.js

How to load external Vue components when I not use npm? I got this error message:

> ReferenceError: VueButtonSpinner is not defined

```js
  Vue.use(VueButtonSpinner);
  var vm = new Vue({
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      el: '#test',
      data: {
        isLoading: false,
        status: ''
      },
      components: {
        VueButtonSpinner
      },
      methods: {
       send() {
        console.log("ypyoyoyoy");
        this.isLoading = true;
        }
      },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-button-spinner@2.2.0/dist/vue-button-spinner.js"></script>

<div id="test">
<button-spinner
     @click="send"
    :isLoading="isLoading" 
    :disabled="isLoading"
    :status="status">
    <span>Submit</span>
</button-spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. The trick is that the script gets imported, but the code defaults to the `default` attribute inside of `window['vue-button-spinner']`:

```js
Vue.component('button-spinner', window['vue-button-spinner'].default);

var vx = new Vue({
  // delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#test',
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      status: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
      console.log("ypyoyoyoy");
      this.isLoading = true;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-button-spinner@2.2.0/dist/vue-button-spinner.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <button-spinner
       @click.native="send"
      :is-loading="isLoading" 
      :disabled="isLoading"
      :status="status">
      <span>Submit</span>
  </button-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been working with modules too much.  This is a more backwards compatible way to do it.  My way presumes the use of modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module loader system, so use `<script type="module" src="whatever.js"></script>` and `import` in `whatever.js`:

From [MDN `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> module: HTML5 For HTML5-compliant browsers the code is treated as a
>   JavaScript module. The processing of the script contents is not
>   affected by the charset and defer attributes. For information on using
>   module, see ES6 in Depth: Modules. Code may behave differently when
>   the module keyword is used.

### whatever.js

```js
import Vue from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js";

import {
  VueButtonSpinner
} from "https://unpkg.com/vue-button-spinner@2.2.0/dist/vue-button-spinner.js";

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "button-spinner": VueButtonSpinner
  }
});
```